# JBoss 4.23 and EJB 2 support

Tags: jboss

Does anyone know if the JBoss 4.2.3 release that is compiled for Java 6 still supports EJB 2?  I'm having issues where it can't cast a class to a certain interface where I never had this problem before and the code hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB2-style beans should still work in the 4.2 release. What interface do you want to cast to? Maybe that particular interface was renamed or moved. You should try not to use container-specific classes.